# failing to get android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, image, permissions

I am trying to get a list of all images on the device. The key command to achieve that is the querying command:

```
       Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
            null, null);
```

which I put within the onCreate() method of the main activity.

within the manifest file I put the required permission (under the root
 node):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

As far as I understand this is all I need to do. Yet this code fails (at the above command) with a security exception, telling me that I need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. I thought I asked for it, but it isn't there. I tried to debug it, and it isn't there. I tried to add a requestPermissions(...) command before the query, and it doesn't work.

the exact error message I get is this:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity componentInfo{com.galamit.pic1/com.galamit.pic1.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=26249, uid=10012 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

I feel I miss something pretty basic, but can't figure out what it might be. Any clue?

EDIT: the request permission part looks like this:

```
if(this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
}
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "it doesn't work" means. Also, you might consider showing your `requestPermissions()` call, as part of a [mcve].

Comment: see the exception I get just a few lines later.

Comment: "see the exception I get just a few lines later" -- that does not explain what "it doesn't work" means with respect to a `requestPermissions()` call. You are not getting that specific exception from the `requestPermissions()` call.

Comment: you are right. sorry. "it doesn't work" means that after the "request permission" call, I still get a "permission denied" when I check for it again.

Comment: but really, I would like to understand why the permission requested in the manifest is not enough. although, at this stage, any work around will do :-)

Comment: By "after the 'request permission' call", do you mean that you are calling `requestPermissions()`, then immediately trying to call `query()`?

Comment: yes. that's basically it. is it wrong?

Comment: I edited the question with request permission code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to understand why the permission requested in the manifest is not enough

It is not supposed to be enough on Android 6.0+ devices, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 24 or higher. For newer apps and newer devices, you also have to [request certain permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is one of those.

The reason why your `requestPermissions()` call is not working is because that call is not synchronous. It is asynchronous. You will not know until `onRequestPermissionsResult()` whether you got the permission or not.

So, you need to isolate your `query()` work into a separate method, that you call from two places:

- Where it is now, if and only if `checkSelfPermission()` says that you already have the permission
- `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, for your particular request, if the result indicates that user agreed to grant you permission